# How to save more Time Machine local snapshots

Tags: time-machine

According to [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204015), there is no local snapshot saved beyond 24 hours:

> Time Machine saves one snapshot of
> your startup disk approximately every hour, and keeps it for 24 hours.
> It keeps an additional snapshot of your last successful Time Machine
> backup until space is needed. And in macOS High Sierra or later,
> another snapshot is saved before installing any macOS update.

Is there a way to overcome this limit? Given the disk space is more than enough (60% free out of 500GB).

A possible workaround is to run `tmutil localsnapshot` manually.

Update 09-22: `tmutil localsnapshot` created snapshot also adhere to the above rule.

Comment: Maybe don't use Time Machine for this? You might be able to roll your own solution using `rsync` https://ss64.com/osx/rsync.html; There might be new problems calling time machine as often as you need?

Comment: Rsync takes up much more space ot only keeps one version. Look at apfs snapshots which carbon copy clone provides an easy to use way

Comment: @user1787331 thanks, I do use Arq, but the time machine local snapshot has its advantage like speedy and smaller overhead.

Comment: @georgexsh I asked a very similar but slightly different question. You may [check it out](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/428197)