# Create persistent local APFS snapshots which later get backed up to external TimeMachine volume

Tags: time-machine, apfs, macos

My scenario is the following:

- I have a folder whose contents changes frequently.

  - To be precise, it's my local backup of my Wordpress upload folder `wp-content/uploads/` which I rsync in a SSH tunnel from my webhost to my local disk.
- Every here and then I consider I'd like to take a snapshot.

  - Analog to git commits, but really want to facilitate that on a filesystem level (APFS), as it's very quick on nowadays SSDs, and the files are mostly binary files (images, etc) not code/text.
- `my-rsync-script.sh && tmutil localsnapshot` does the job perfectly.

  - Mounting the different localsnapshots side by side shows how the folder contents changed over time, and gives me the chance to restore the entire folder or parts, if necessary.
  - Problem is that local snapshots are [only kept 24h or so](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/427594). You can not tell tmutil "This is a snapshot of importance, please keep it, possibly add a remark/note".
- In addition to persisting them reliably locally (unless space runs out or another of *my specified* housecleaning policies kicks in)…

  - … I would then love that at the next TimeMachine run to an externally connected TimeMachine volume these "manually created hence worthy snapshots" are persisted to the TimeMachine backup.

Is this possible?

Comment: This is possible but not easy. You can create and manage APFS snapshots without time machine. I think this would work though: Disable Time Machine fully, this will also erase existing snapshots, then use a util like CCC to re-enable snapshots.  You should then be able to use `tmutil localsnapshot` but time machine won't auto-delete them. More details here: https://eclecticlight.co/2022/02/10/managing-snapshots-how-to-stop-them-eating-free-space/ (And as a hack, if you keep a snapshot mounted it can't be deleted. Also this would be easier if you make a new APFS volume just for this)

Comment: Thx for your reply! Learned a lot more on the subject now. See the chances & limitations clearer now. Key part: "In APFS, snapshots can only be made of complete volumes." That means I should transform that "version-managed" media library backup folder into a standalone APFS volume. Otherwise it will always include my entire boot disk contents in the snapshots. What remains unanswered: If I create 10 snapshots and only then run a TimeMachine backup of that volume only the latest snapshot will be saved instead of all 10. Need to find out how to backup snapshots themselves to an external volume.